# Android: IntentService freezes the UI in my Activity under certain conditions. How to prevent it?

Tags: android, asynchronous, intentservice

IntentService works fine and asynchronously when I install my app for the first time (calling "startService" from within the launcher Activity's "onCreate()" doesn't freeze the Activity UI). However, when I install it again over an existing installation, the launcher Activity's UI hangs until the started IntentService's "onHandleIntent" completes (even if I put "startActivity" in an "AsyncTask doInBackground" or "Handler post"). What gives? I'm presuming IntentService should always be asynchronous, but in such cases it isn't. How do I guarantee that "onHandleIntent" is always carried out asynchronously and doesn't block the UI of the Activity from which it was called? This would seem to affect the app when somebody installs an update etc. Or is nobody able to reproduce this problem on their devices?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to resolve this? I'm seeing the same issue, I think...

Comment: No, I didn't resolve this issue.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432310/4997704